# Vue default value dynamic select options

Tags: vue.js, html-select, v-for

I've tried my best to keep the following code as concise as possible. 
The goal of this code: get tickets (products) via an api (data.json in this example) and display them in a table for users to buy.

The part I'm struggling with? Each product has a number which represents the maximum amount that can be bought per user. I'm showing these values dynamically in options, which works. To give you a better understanding, here is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-currying-gocrw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Everything works as expected and wanted, but what truly would be great is to add a leading zero to the option numbers. Now when a user selects some tickets and changes his mind he won't be able to do so.

**EDIT:**

If you look at the code via URL above, it is indeed now fixed (thanks to the +1 solution and using the index as my values). Now I'd like to have 0 selected as the default value. I'm not really sure on how to achieve this.

The for-loop looks like this:

```html
<select v-model="selectedTickets[product.id]">
 <option v-for="(maximum, n) in Number(product.product_meta.maximum) + 1" :value="n" :key="n">
  {{ n }}
 </option>
</select>
```

Data function looks like this:

```js
data() {
        return {
          selectedTickets: {},
          products: null
        };
      }
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:

```html
<option value="0"> 0 </option>
```

Before your `v-for` loop on `options`, so it would look like this:

```html
<select v-model="selectedTickets[product.id]">
  <option value="0"> 0 </option>
  <option
    v-for="(maximum, n) in Number(product.product_meta.maximum)"
    :value="maximum"
    :key="n"
  >
    {{ maximum }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Now, that first option would be the default one, and user would be able to go back anytime.

One other thing that you can do is just to add `+1` to `product.product_meta.maximum` and use `n` for `:value` instead of `maximum`.

The best option, though, would be to create one method called `getSelectableOptions(product)` that will return the array of selectable options for given product, for example `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and then you can loop through it, that way your code will be cleaner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I sort of solved it by your +1 solution (thank you very much). But still the option boxes remain empty and not with default 0 zero selected. I think it might have something to do with the v-model...

Comment: Just set `v-model` attributes to `0` upon creation. You can do that in `mounted` method in your component. 

More about that read here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted ;


If my answer helped you and answered your question, please accept it, for future reference. Thank you! 

Also, let me know if you have issues with that `mounted` method logic.

Comment: @D.Bleumink It just crossed my mind, you can actually do that logic for setting `v-model` `selectedTickets[product.id]` to `0` in your `then` method - when retrieving those products.

Comment: Those are some good options! Haven't managed to solve it though. The `selectedTickets[product.id]` data property is an object. So I don't really know how to set that to `0` while keeping the object dynamic.

Comment: @D.Bleumink Here is how you can do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-hugle-b249s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark . Let me know if this is ok.

Comment: You did it! Great trick, and makes a lot of sense as well. My mind was just stuck haha. Will mark your answer as the answer. Have a great day and stay save!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a clear button at the bottom to reset all the selection

```
<button @click="selectedTickets={}">Reset</button>
```

It is also possible to implement individual clear buttons for each select input like the following:

```
<select v-model="selectedTickets[product.id]">
    <option
        v-for="(maximum, n) in Number(product.product_meta.maximum)"
        :value="maximum"
        :key="n"
    >
        {{ maximum }}
    </option>
</select>
<button
    @click="resetSelection(product.id)"
    v-if="product.id in selectedTickets"
>
    Clear
</button>
```

Then create a method in the `methods` section

```
resetSelection: function(productId) {
   delete this.selectedTickets[productId];
}
```

This will clear individual selects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I managed to make a clear data method already in the meantime :). Maybe you could still help me with with a default selected value though... See my edit.